# How can I display 'NA' for blank values of Datetime datatype in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have a field 'Clockin' which will display the Date and Time,Now i have some blank values in it.how can make blank values to 'NA'?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a formula for the `Value` property to check if it is blank:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Clockin.Value), "NA", Fields!Clockin.Value)
```